# awk if find pattern skip n lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

How to `skip N lines` when a pattern is found in awk?

```
awk '{if ($0~/pattern/) skip N lines; else print $0}'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me show you how to make that awk solution more idiomatic (refer to the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) on stackoverflow).

Starting with:

```bsh
$ seq 10 20 | awk '{if ($0 ~ /11/) {n=NR+6}; if (NR<n) next; print $0}'
10
17
18
19
20
```

First, we'll take the `if` statements, and turn them into `condition {action}` lines

```bsh
awk '
    $0 ~ /11/ {n=NR+6}
    NR < n {next}
    {print $0}
'
```

Then, we'll use `$0` as the default value for some things:

```bsh
awk '
    /11/ {n=NR+6}
    NR < n {next}
    {print}
'
```

Then, we'll take `{print}` as the default action if the condition is true

```bsh
awk '
    /11/ {n=NR+6}
    NR < n {next}
    1
'
```

Then, we'll invert the `NR < n` condition to remove the `next`

```bsh
awk '
    /11/ {n=NR+6}
    NR >= n
'
```

And we can one-liner-ize it:

```bsh
awk '/11/ {n=NR+6} NR >= n'
```

This produces the same output

```bsh
$ seq 10 20 | awk '/11/ {n=NR+6} NR >= n'
10
17
18
19
20
```

Comparing:

```bsh
awk '{if ($0 ~ /11/) {n=NR+6}; if (NR<n) next; print $0}'
awk '/11/ {n=NR+6} NR >= n'
```

As a last step, you might want to pass the pattern and the value of N as parameters into awk, so they don't have to be hardcoded. This inflates the awk call but might be more flexible for you:

```bsh
awk -v patt="11" -v N=6 '$0 ~ patt {n = NR + N} NR >= n'
```

By placing the parameters after the awk script, `-v` can  be dropped, making the command a bit shorter:

```bsh
awk '$0 ~ patt {n = NR + N} NR >= n' patt=11 N=6
```

One advantage to putting the variables after the awk body is they can get different values for each file:

```bsh
awk '$0 ~ patt {n = NR + N} NR >= n' patt=11 N=6 file1 N=10 file2
```

Comment: FWIW, here is the GNU sed equivalent to your one-liner-ized awk command: ``sed '/11/,+5 d'`` (lines matching pattern `/11/` and the `5` next lines are deleted from the output)

Answer (score 2):

**N** = number of lines to skip

```
awk '{if ($0~/pattern/) {n=NR+N;} if (NR<n) next; print $0;}'
```